# Is there a simple Regex to check date format pattern?

Tags: javascript

I found a lot of regex that check date values (numbers) that match the format, but I don't want to check this. I give the user the option to write its own custom pattern date like:

```
    d-mm-yyyy
    MM/dd/yy
    yyyy.mm.d
```

I want to check this strings "MM/dd/yy" written by user is valid and don't has other characters than d, DD, MM, ... with ".", "/", "-" between them.
Strange didn't find any regex that check all simple patterns, found lots of regex that check the numbers, not the pattern itself.

Comment: So have you tried any regexs already?

Comment: https://github.com/velusgautam/reuse/blob/master/src/isValidDate.js

See this code if it helps

Comment: https://github.com/velusgautam/reuse/blob/master/src/getDateObject.js

if you need date object. But you need to always pass dd-mm-yyyy or yyyy/mm/dd format the splitter can be anything like - or / or .

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
const regex = /(\d{1,2}(?:-|\/)\d{1,2}(?:-|\/)(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))|(\d{4}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})/gm

// valid cases
regex.test('1-01-2000')
regex.test('12-1-2000')
regex.test('10/10/11')
regex.test('10/1/2011')
regex.test('1/1/2011')
regex.test('2000.12.1')
regex.test('2000.1.11')
```

This will provide a very robust method for testing validity of dates.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I reworked my answer. So if you want to make some kind of Date patterns validator, check code below. It is not only RegExp, but also some function logic to catch duplicates etc. Read comments

```js
const test = (str) => {
  // Check main pattern
  const m = str.match(/^([md]{1,2}|y{4}|y{2})[-\/\.]([md]{1,2}|y{4}|y{2})[-\/\.]([md]{1,2}|y{4}|y{2})$/i);
  
  // Print false
  const noMatch = () => console.log('Not match!', str);
  
  // If no matched groups
  if(!m) {
    noMatch();
    return false;
  }
  // Unique obj
  const unique = {};
  
  // Check if all match is unique
  const mArr = ["d", "m", "y"];
  for(let i = 1; i < m.length; i++) {
    const mStr = m[i];
    // Loop avaliable char
    for(let i = 0; i < mArr.length; i++) {
      const re = new RegExp(`^[${mArr[i]}]+$`, "i");
      // If match char
      if(re.test(mStr)) {
        // If already in unique object
        if(unique[mArr[i]]) {
          noMatch();
          return false;
        } else unique[mArr[i]] = true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Match
  console.log('Matched!', str);
}

test('dd-mm-yyyy');
test('YYYY/MM/DD');
test('dd.mm.yy');
test('dd.dd.yyyy');
test('dd|mm|yyyy');
test('ddd-mmm-yyyy');
test('dd/mm/yyy');
```

Comment: this would allow `ddd-ddd-ddd`

Comment: I mean again `dm-dm-yyyy`, `dm-yyyy.yyyy`

Comment: Well)) we show principle here, then AngularOne should adopt it for his case